# Permissions with discord.py without using ctx

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

So, I wanted to set up a purge command for discord.py, but everyone is able to use it. I obviously want it just for people who have the manage messages permission. I don't really understand `ctx` commands yet, so I'd like to avoid that for now, and the only answers I can find to this involve using `ctx`, and setting it up as `@bot.command`. What I have right now is:

```
    elif message.content.startswith ('jb!purge'):
        searchargs = message.content.split(" ")
        if(len(searchargs) > 1):
            if(len(searchargs) > 2):
                await message.channel.send("Too many numbers! Please try `jb!purge <number>`")
            elif(len(searchargs) == 2):
                if has_permissions(manage_messages = True):
                    try:
                        output = int(searchargs[1])
                        await message.channel.purge(limit=output)
                    except ValueError:
                        await message.channel.send("That's not a number, silly!")
                else:
                    await message.channel.send("Go get the perms first, then try again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TextChannel.permissions_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.permissions_for) using the [`TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel) object you have from [`Message.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel). You can simply pass it the [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) object from [`Message.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author).
With the [`Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions) object, you can then simply check [`Permissions.manage_messages`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.manage_messages).

You should really look into using the [commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html) though.